# How to know if Close comes from RadPane or RadPaneGroup

Tags: wpf, telerik, raddocking

We have following Raddocking declared:

```
<telerik:RadDocking 
        x:Name="RadDocking" 
        RetainPaneSizeMode="DockingAndFloating" 
        Close="RadDocking_OnClose" 
        CloseButtonPosition="InPaneAndGroup"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        Loaded="RadDocking_OnLoaded"
        Visibility="{Binding IsMenuLoaded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer>
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" DropDownDisplayMode="WhenNeeded">
                </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
</telerik:RadDocking>
```

As you can see we use the CloseButtonPosition InPaneAndGroup.
And we implement our own logic on the Close event.
But I want to check if we clicked on the close button in the pane, or on the close button of the group.
Is there a way to know this?
I've checked the Sender & StateChangedeventArgs, but they seem always only to hold 1 pane (the one that is active). But I would really need to know if it is the groupbutton or panebutton which is pressed, because we will handle other logic. 
Anyone any thoughts?

Comment: If you have a Telerik account, their support is pretty fast and will be able to answer a question like this in under 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more looking around in the Telerik forum I found a solution that comes very close to what I need. Only a pity there is no build in solution for something like this. 
I can't imagine there is no need to a close all functionality and close tab functionality on the same time.

That said here is the source I based my solution on:
[Determine Source of Close](https://www.telerik.com/forums/determine-source-of-close#CYUh-nmN0kWIXnLwDzH-5w)

Here is the solution I made up:

> First I implemented the logic mentioned in above link to the Preview on closing to set a flag that signifies that the group button was clicked or not:

```
    private void RadDocking_OnPreviewClose(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        RadPane pane = e.Panes.ToList()[0];
        Point pt = Mouse.GetPosition(pane);
        if (pt.X <= pane.ActualWidth)
        {
            _groupClosing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _groupClosing = true;
        }
    }
```

> After that I just check on the flag in the closing method to handle the different logics

```
    private void RadDocking_OnClose(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_groupClosing)
        {
            _regionManager.GetRegion(Constants.MainRegion).Remove(e.Panes.First().Content);
        }
        else
        {
            _regionManager.GetRegion(Constants.MainRegion).RemoveAll();
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help others in their quest for a similar problem.